# Flink program cannot submit when i follow flink-1.4's quickstart and use "./bin/flink run examples/streaming/SocketWindowWordCount.jar --port 9000"

Tags: apache-flink

Flink-1.4 quickstart address: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/quickstart/setup_quickstart.html.

When I use "./bin/start-local.sh" to start flink following flink-1.4's quickstart, then i check http://localhost:8081/ and make sure everything is running, then i use "./bin/flink run examples/streaming/SocketWindowWordCount.jar --port 9000" to submit .jar and i got following info, and i can't submit successfully.

```
------------------------------------------------------------
 The program finished with the following exception:

org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: The program execution failed: Couldn't retrieve the JobExecutionResult from the JobManager.
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.ClusterClient.run(ClusterClient.java:492)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.StandaloneClusterClient.submitJob(StandaloneClusterClient.java:105)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.ClusterClient.run(ClusterClient.java:456)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamContextEnvironment.execute(StreamContextEnvironment.java:66)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.examples.socket.SocketWindowWordCount.main(SocketWindowWordCount.java:92)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:525)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.invokeInteractiveModeForExecution(PackagedProgram.java:417)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.ClusterClient.run(ClusterClient.java:396)
    at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend.executeProgram(CliFrontend.java:802)
    at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend.run(CliFrontend.java:282)
    at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend.parseParameters(CliFrontend.java:1054)
    at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend$1.call(CliFrontend.java:1101)
    at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend$1.call(CliFrontend.java:1098)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:423)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1556)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.security.HadoopSecurityContext.runSecured(HadoopSecurityContext.java:41)
    at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend.main(CliFrontend.java:1098)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobExecutionException: Couldn't retrieve the JobExecutionResult from the JobManager.
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobClient.awaitJobResult(JobClient.java:300)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobClient.submitJobAndWait(JobClient.java:387)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.ClusterClient.run(ClusterClient.java:481)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobClientActorConnectionTimeoutException: Lost connection to the JobManager.
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobClientActor.handleMessage(JobClientActor.java:219)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.akka.FlinkUntypedActor.handleLeaderSessionID(FlinkUntypedActor.java:104)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.akka.FlinkUntypedActor.onReceive(FlinkUntypedActor.java:71)
    at akka.actor.UntypedActor$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(UntypedActor.scala:165)
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:502)
    at akka.actor.UntypedActor.aroundReceive(UntypedActor.scala:95)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:526)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:495)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:257)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:224)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:234)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

---

I have tried flink-1.3 with the same install steps,i can submit .jar and run correctly, but flink-1.4 can not work, anyone knows what's wrong?

In addition,when I use "./bin/start-local.sh" to start flink-1.4.0, i check "http://localhost:8081/" and everything is running, but jobmanager logs show errors, the log file is as follow:

---

```
2018-01-26 14:55:01,012 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.clusterframework.standalone.StandaloneResourceManager  - TaskManager 3b3e2dd7f3f29662b6312e875dd496dc has started.

2018-01-26 14:55:01,053 WARN  akka.remote.ReliableDeliverySupervisor                        - Association with remote system [akka.tcp://flink@pyn-virtual-machine:44785] has failed, address is now gated for [5000] ms. Reason: [[B cannot be cast to [C] 

2018-01-26 14:55:10,589 ERROR akka.remote.Remoting                                        - [B cannot be cast to [C
java.lang.ClassCastException: [B cannot be cast to [C
    at akka.remote.artery.FastHash$.ofString(LruBoundedCache.scala:18)
    at akka.remote.serialization.ActorRefResolveCache.hash(ActorRefResolveCache.scala:61)
    at akka.remote.serialization.ActorRefResolveCache.hash(ActorRefResolveCache.scala:55)
    at akka.remote.artery.LruBoundedCache.getOrCompute(LruBoundedCache.scala:110)
    at akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider.resolveActorRef(RemoteActorRefProvider.scala:403)
    at akka.actor.SerializedActorRef.readResolve(ActorRef.scala:433)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadResolve(ObjectStreamClass.java:1250)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2087)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1585)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2346)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2240)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2078)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1585)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:422)
    at akka.serialization.JavaSerializer$$anonfun$1.apply(Serializer.scala:328)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
    at akka.serialization.JavaSerializer.fromBinary(Serializer.scala:328)
    at akka.serialization.Serialization.akka$serialization$Serialization$$deserializeByteArray(Serialization.scala:156)
    at akka.serialization.Serialization$$anonfun$deserialize$2.apply(Serialization.scala:142)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
    at akka.serialization.Serialization.deserialize(Serialization.scala:136)
    at akka.remote.MessageSerializer$.deserialize(MessageSerializer.scala:30)
    at akka.remote.DefaultMessageDispatcher.payload$lzycompute$1(Endpoint.scala:64)
    at akka.remote.DefaultMessageDispatcher.payload$1(Endpoint.scala:64)
    at akka.remote.DefaultMessageDispatcher.dispatch(Endpoint.scala:82)
    at akka.remote.EndpointReader$$anonfun$akka$remote$EndpointReader$$deliverAndAck$1.apply(Endpoint.scala:1047)
    at akka.remote.EndpointReader$$anonfun$akka$remote$EndpointReader$$deliverAndAck$1.apply(Endpoint.scala:1046)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:891)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1334)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
    at akka.remote.EndpointReader.akka$remote$EndpointReader$$deliverAndAck(Endpoint.scala:1046)
    at akka.remote.EndpointReader$$anonfun$receive$2.applyOrElse(Endpoint.scala:980)
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:502)
    at akka.remote.EndpointActor.aroundReceive(Endpoint.scala:446)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:526)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:495)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:257)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:224)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:234)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)

2018-01-26 14:55:19,206 WARN  akka.remote.ReliableDeliverySupervisor                        - Association with remote system [akka.tcp://flink@pyn-virtual-machine:44785] has failed, address is now gated for [5000] ms. Reason: [Disassociated] 

2018-01-26 14:56:04,754 WARN  akka.remote.ReliableDeliverySupervisor                        - Association with remote system [akka.tcp://flink@pyn-virtual-machine:37261] has failed, address is now gated for [5000] ms. Reason: [Disassociated]
```

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this. So long as I have netcat running, listening on port 9000, this example works for me with a stock 1.4.0 release. Maybe look in the jobmanager logs to see if there are any clues there.

Comment: I have nectat running on port 9000 before i submit .jar file. and then i have checked jobmanager logs, i found that when i use "./bin/start-local.sh" , the logs show errors java.lang.ClassCastException [B cannot be cast to [C that  lead to taskmanager  can not registered at jobmanager successfully.I wonder what has caused " java.lang.ClassCastException [B cannot be cast to [C".

Comment: My Flink used to work in Flink 1.3, the same error for Flink 1.4. @anan have you figured out how to fix it?

Comment: Sorry,i don't know either. i am using Flink 1.3 now.