# Apache flink (Stable version 1.6.2) does not work

Tags: java, macos, ubuntu, apache-flink, stream-processing

Recently, the stable version (1.6.2) of apache flink was released. I read [this instruction](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/quickstart/setup_quickstart.html). But when I run the following command:

```
./bin/flink run examples/streaming/SocketWindowWordCount.jar --port 9000
```

I get the following error:

```
 The program finished with the following exception:

org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: Job failed. (JobID: 264564a337d4c6705bde681b34010d28)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.rest.RestClusterClient.submitJob(RestClusterClient.java:268)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.ClusterClient.run(ClusterClient.java:486)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamContextEnvironment.execute(StreamContextEnvironment.java:66)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.examples.socket.SocketWindowWordCount.main(SocketWindowWordCount.java:92)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:529)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.invokeInteractiveModeForExecution(PackagedProgram.java:421)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.ClusterClient.run(ClusterClient.java:426)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.executeProgram(CliFrontend.java:816)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.runProgram(CliFrontend.java:290)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.run(CliFrontend.java:216)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.parseParameters(CliFrontend.java:1053)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.lambda$main$11(CliFrontend.java:1129)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1836)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.security.HadoopSecurityContext.runSecured(HadoopSecurityContext.java:41)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.main(CliFrontend.java:1129)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobExecutionException: Job execution failed.
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobResult.toJobExecutionResult(JobResult.java:146)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.rest.RestClusterClient.submitJob(RestClusterClient.java:265)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.source.SocketTextStreamFunction.run(SocketTextStreamFunction.java:96)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSource.run(StreamSource.java:94)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSource.run(StreamSource.java:58)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.SourceStreamTask.run(SourceStreamTask.java:99)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:300)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:711)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I found this link:[Flink program cannot submit when i follow flink-1.4's quickstart and use "./bin/flink run examples/streaming/SocketWindowWordCount.jar --port 9000"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48438501/flink-program-cannot-submit-when-i-follow-flink-1-4s-quickstart-and-use-bin). However, it didn't help. I tried with `Flink 1.6.2 with Hadoop® 2.8` as well as `Flink 1.5.5 with Hadoop® 2.8` on `mac os` and `ubuntu`. But I just got the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the annoying problem by reading the `nc -h` (in Linux):

```
connect to somewhere:   nc [-options] hostname port[s] [ports] ... 
listen for inbound: nc -l -p port [-options] [hostname] [port]
```

So for listening a port, `-p` is mandatory, and I tried the following command:

```
nc -l -p 9000
```

and It worked.

Comment: Interesting. When I look at `nc -h` it says: `-p port  Specify local port for remote connects (cannot use with -l)`.

Comment: I'm using the version of nc that Apple ships in /usr/bin/nc as part of MacOS 10.13.6. What version are you using?

Comment: Sorry, my answer is for the `Linux`. I edited my answer. However, I cannot get results from `flink` in `mac os`. It always says that: `an illegal reflective access operation has occurred`.

Comment: Perhaps you are trying to use Java 9, which isn't supported (yet)?

Comment: Maybe, I ran `java -version`, and here is the result:`openjdk version "11.0.1"`.

Comment: Flink currently only supports Java 8, so yes, that version of openjdk is too new.

Comment: So, I changed the default version of Java in `mac os` to Java 8, and finally it worked! @DavidAnderson

Answer (score 1):

Works fine for me. Only difference I can see is that I'm using the version of Flink without hadoop, but I doubt that's the issue.

`java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused` usually means that there is no service listening on port 9000. You should have netcat running on this port via

```
$ nc -l 9000
```

(see https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/quickstart/setup_quickstart.html#run-the-example). If netcat is running, and it's not working, maybe try another port? It might also help to check all the log files for additional clues.

Comment: I tried another port, but it didn't work. I also checked log files and tried with Flink without Hadoop, but I still get the error. It's very annoying.

Comment: Have you tried one of the other examples that doesn't involve netcat? E.g., `./bin/flink run examples/streaming/WordCount.jar --output /tmp/test`.

Comment: What version of Java are you using?

Comment: Yes, I tried other examples and it works. But it doesn't work for `SocketWindowWordCount.jar`. The version is `1.8.0_171`.

Comment: Perhaps you have a firewall preventing network connections; you might want to verify that the network is available. In one terminal window run `nc -lk 9000` and in another run `nc localhost 9000`, after which, every line you type in each window should be echoed into the other.

Comment: After running `nc localhost 9000`, I got the error:`localhost [127.0.0.1] 9000 (?) : Connection refused`. Also, I run `telnet localhost 9000`, and I got: `telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused`. I tried other ports, but it didn't make any difference.

Comment: Right, so the problem has nothing to do with Flink -- it's a basic networking problem.

Comment: Yes, I solved the problem, see my answer. Thanks for your help!