# Unable to run flink example program,Connection refused

Tags: java, apache-flink

```
./bin/flink run examples/streaming/SocketWindowWordCount.jar --port 9000
```

According to the official QuickStart directly run the example program.Log as fololws.The reason seems to be java.net.ConnectException.I'm sure port is not being used and firewall is closed.

```
root@maple-PC:/home/maple/Downloads/flink-1.4.2# ./bin/flink run examples/streaming/SocketWindowWordCount.jar --port 9000
Cluster configuration: Standalone cluster with JobManager at localhost/127.0.0.1:6123
Using address localhost:6123 to connect to JobManager.
JobManager web interface address http://localhost:8081
Starting execution of program
Submitting job with JobID: b371f7847302f8930115f093c7e32d3d. Waiting for job completion.
Connected to JobManager at Actor[akka.tcp://flink@localhost:6123/user/jobmanager#-198847679] with leader session id 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000.
12/15/2018 01:06:20 Job execution switched to status RUNNING.
12/15/2018 01:06:20 Source: Socket Stream -> Flat Map(1/1) switched to SCHEDULED 
12/15/2018 01:06:20 TriggerWindow(TumblingProcessingTimeWindows(5000), ReducingStateDescriptor{serializer=org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.runtime.PojoSerializer@9cfdeb73, reduceFunction=org.apache.flink.streaming.examples.socket.SocketWindowWordCount$1@71687585}, ProcessingTimeTrigger(), WindowedStream.reduce(WindowedStream.java:241)) -> Sink: Unnamed(1/1) switched to SCHEDULED 
12/15/2018 01:06:20 Source: Socket Stream -> Flat Map(1/1) switched to DEPLOYING 
12/15/2018 01:06:20 TriggerWindow(TumblingProcessingTimeWindows(5000), ReducingStateDescriptor{serializer=org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.runtime.PojoSerializer@9cfdeb73, reduceFunction=org.apache.flink.streaming.examples.socket.SocketWindowWordCount$1@71687585}, ProcessingTimeTrigger(), WindowedStream.reduce(WindowedStream.java:241)) -> Sink: Unnamed(1/1) switched to DEPLOYING 
12/15/2018 01:06:21 TriggerWindow(TumblingProcessingTimeWindows(5000), ReducingStateDescriptor{serializer=org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.runtime.PojoSerializer@9cfdeb73, reduceFunction=org.apache.flink.streaming.examples.socket.SocketWindowWordCount$1@71687585}, ProcessingTimeTrigger(), WindowedStream.reduce(WindowedStream.java:241)) -> Sink: Unnamed(1/1) switched to RUNNING 
12/15/2018 01:06:21 Source: Socket Stream -> Flat Map(1/1) switched to RUNNING 
12/15/2018 01:06:21 Source: Socket Stream -> Flat Map(1/1) switched to FAILED 
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.source.SocketTextStreamFunction.run(SocketTextStreamFunction.java:96)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSource.run(StreamSource.java:86)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSource.run(StreamSource.java:55)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.SourceStreamTask.run(SourceStreamTask.java:94)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:718)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

12/15/2018 01:06:21 Job execution switched to status FAILING.
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.source.SocketTextStreamFunction.run(SocketTextStreamFunction.java:96)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSource.run(StreamSource.java:86)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSource.run(StreamSource.java:55)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.SourceStreamTask.run(SourceStreamTask.java:94)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:718)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
12/15/2018 01:06:21 TriggerWindow(TumblingProcessingTimeWindows(5000), ReducingStateDescriptor{serializer=org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.runtime.PojoSerializer@9cfdeb73, reduceFunction=org.apache.flink.streaming.examples.socket.SocketWindowWordCount$1@71687585}, ProcessingTimeTrigger(), WindowedStream.reduce(WindowedStream.java:241)) -> Sink: Unnamed(1/1) switched to CANCELING 
12/15/2018 01:06:21 TriggerWindow(TumblingProcessingTimeWindows(5000), ReducingStateDescriptor{serializer=org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.runtime.PojoSerializer@9cfdeb73, reduceFunction=org.apache.flink.streaming.examples.socket.SocketWindowWordCount$1@71687585}, ProcessingTimeTrigger(), WindowedStream.reduce(WindowedStream.java:241)) -> Sink: Unnamed(1/1) switched to CANCELED 

------------------------------------------------------------
 The program finished with the following exception:

org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: The program execution failed: Job execution failed.
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.ClusterClient.run(ClusterClient.java:492)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.StandaloneClusterClient.submitJob(StandaloneClusterClient.java:105)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.ClusterClient.run(ClusterClient.java:456)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamContextEnvironment.execute(StreamContextEnvironment.java:66)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.examples.socket.SocketWindowWordCount.main(SocketWindowWordCount.java:92)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:525)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.invokeInteractiveModeForExecution(PackagedProgram.java:417)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.ClusterClient.run(ClusterClient.java:396)
    at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend.executeProgram(CliFrontend.java:802)
    at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend.run(CliFrontend.java:282)
    at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend.parseParameters(CliFrontend.java:1054)
    at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend$1.call(CliFrontend.java:1101)
    at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend$1.call(CliFrontend.java:1098)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1807)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.security.HadoopSecurityContext.runSecured(HadoopSecurityContext.java:41)
    at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend.main(CliFrontend.java:1098)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobExecutionException: Job execution failed.
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager$$anonfun$handleMessage$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$6.apply$mcV$sp(JobManager.scala:897)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager$$anonfun$handleMessage$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$6.apply(JobManager.scala:840)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager$$anonfun$handleMessage$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$6.apply(JobManager.scala:840)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
    at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:39)
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:415)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: 拒绝连接 (Connection refused)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.source.SocketTextStreamFunction.run(SocketTextStreamFunction.java:96)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSource.run(StreamSource.java:86)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSource.run(StreamSource.java:55)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.SourceStreamTask.run(SourceStreamTask.java:94)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:718)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 8):

Those socket stream examples expect that a server (netcat) has been started and is bound to the port before the flink job starts. Normally this is done via

```
nc -lk 9000
```

but some versions of netcat need

```
nc -l -p 9000
```

See [Apache flink (Stable version 1.6.2) does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53355002/apache-flink-stable-version-1-6-2-does-not-work) for more discussion of this.

Comment: It works.I had been using `nc -l 9000`Only need to join -p options`nc -l -p 9000`.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can tell from the last stack that the ```SocketTextStreamFunction`` got a connection refused when trying to connect localhost:9000 with socket. So it's a problem of the sender(the program) or the receiver(your local machine's port). Maybe you can attach the port status of 9000 to let us know more, which can help solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a problem with flink/the flink demos.  I have the same problem.  Localhost to localhost.  If I run the demo multiple times, I will get failure after failure, but then it will connect and work fine.  All the while nc is waiting there.  I started that with `ncat -v -l 9000` so it shows when anyone tries to connect.

The ncat output using `-v` showed that nothing was trying to connect to ncat UNTIL I was actually successful running the demo.

So, I ran this basic test: https://www.linode.com/docs/networking/diagnostics/netcat/netcat/#using-netcat-as-a-server

The result is that that worked perfectly!  I could connect between two open windows and talk to myself to my heart's content.

I really think it's the example (maybe it doesn't wait long enough before giving up?)

## Setup

### OS

CentOS7.4,
Linux my_host 3.10.0-957.5.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Feb 1 14:54:57 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

### Ncat

Tried version on system: 7.50

Also tried version downloaded from nmap.org: 7.80.

### Java

java version "1.8.0_221"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_221-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.221-b11, mixed mode)

Comment: What operating system was this?